# If condition in java does not print the output correctly

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 0;
    if (x > 0) 
        System.out.println("positive ");
        System.out.println("zero ");
        System.out.println("negative"); 
}
```

---

output:

```
zero 
negative
```

Why does the program not print the positive but prints zero and negative?

Comment: Can we close this question?

Comment: If you would rewrite your code, it would look like `if (x > 0) {System.out.println("positive ");}`
`System.out.println("zero ");`
`System.out.println("negative");`
As you can see, last 2 prints don't go under If-clause

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
if (x > 0) {
    System.out.println("positive ");
} else if (x == 0) {
    System.out.println("zero ");
} else {
    System.out.println("negative");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that it will print `positive` when value of `x` is 0. `x > 0` will return false so it will skip `System.out.println("positive ");` and it will print other 2 lines because your if block ended in `System.out.println("positive ");` line itself

Answer (score 0):

Because x is set to 0
so the if condition is never verified and the "positive" statement is not executed

You probably wanted to write something like

```
if (x > 0)
    System.out.println("positive ");
if (x == 0)
    System.out.println("zero ");
if (x < 0)
    System.out.println("negative");
```

Comment: Not wrong, but the answer containing the `else if / else` is obviously a pinch better, since you can avoid 2 comparissions, if the first is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't put the brackets so the

```
 System.out.println("positive ");
```

is coming inside the If condition and obviously  if condition is not true that's why it is not printing the positive.

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing `positive` because it fails the `if` condition. The value of your `x` is `0` which is not greater than `0`. It does print `zero` and `negative` because it falls outside of your `if` condtion due to the lack of curly braces. If no `{}` then only the first line after the `if` condition is executed.

In the off chance that you want your code to print all three i.e. `positive` `negative` and `zero` when your `x > 0` (can't see why you would do that), then you are missing curly braces and your code should look like:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 0;
    if (x > 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("positive ");
        System.out.println("zero ");
        System.out.println("negative"); 
    }
}
```

For your code, this will print nothing because it fails the `if` condition so nothing inside curly braces will be executed.

But if you want your program to print `positive` when `>0`, `negative` when `<0` and `0` when `=0` then @hsz's answer is the one your are looking for.